# Output of shuffling a string is printed on 2 lines of output

Tags: python, random

I've decide to practice solving anagrams, something I'm very bad at. I got 1000 most common words of English language, filtered those under 5 letters and over 9 and then wrote a simple script:

```py
import random
from random import randint

words = []
file = 'new_words.txt'

with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        words.append(line)

while True:
    i = randint(0, (len(words)-1))

    question_list = list(words[i])
    random.shuffle(question_list)

    print(f"{''.join(question_list)}")
    print(f'Please solve the anagram. Type "exit" to quit of "next" to pass:\n')
    answer = input()

    if answer == 'exit':
        break
    elif answer == 'pass':
        pass
    elif answer == words[i]:
        print('Correct!')
    elif answer != words[i]:
        print('Epic fail...\n\n')
```

Now for some reason the output of  the line `print(f"{''.join(question_list)}")` is printed over 2 lines like so:

```
o
nzcieger
```

Which is an anagram for 'recognize'. It also prints random numbers on letters per line:

```
ly
erla
```

Sometimes the whole anagram is printed properly.

I can't figure out what's causing this.

**EDIT:** [Link to my filtered file with words](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FJEkf04YvbNomBAqJCvz9WbSaBtOjxRQ)

Comment: It seems like the issue could be with the formatting of "new_words.txt" having pesky newlines. Could you post or link to "new_words.txt" so that we can reproduce this issue?

Comment: FYI, the `f"{...}"` around `join` is entirely superfluous.

Comment: Added link at the bottom of original post

Comment: @deceze, I know but at first when it was working in a strange way I thought that it might be something with formatting so I tried printing it as formatted string instead. Obviously, it didn't help.

Comment: OP, some links for your awareness: [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) and [`file.readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to strip the newlines out of the word.

Basically, your text file is actually formatted as a word on each line and a '\n' character at the end of each line. When you call `random.shuffle(question_list)`, your are shuffling the characters of the word along with the newline character, so the newline is also shuffled! When you print out the 'shuffled' word, Python prints the word out with the newline, so you get the word randomly split between two lines.

In order to solve this issue, you can probably use the `str.strip()` function (but that would require you cast the list to a string) or just add this to below `question_list = list(words[i])`:

```
for character in question_list:
    if character == '\n':
        question_list.remove(character)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your solution worked, but I figured out it will be even easier to simply add ```strip()``` to the part where I'm reading the file and building the word list: ```words.append(line.strip())```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this below `question_list = list(words[i]):` to remove the new line character read from the file for each of the line.

```
question_list.remove('\n')
```

Since the new line character occur only one time in the list we don't need to iterate over the list. It will just remove the first occurrence of `'\n'` from the list.

Or

```
del question_list[-1]
```

cause we know the exact index location of `\n`